# git push: default parameters for each branch

Tags: git

I would like to make sure that git commands (e.g., git push) always use certain parameters depending on the current working branch.

I know that using git hooks (e.g., pre-push) I would be able to do different things depending on the current branch. I'm still missing the part of changing the parameters of the git command.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Which parameters, and what values should they take?

Comment: What chris said, plus, is it "e.g. git push", or "for git push"? Any command or 1 is a very different question.

Comment: @Chris, for example I'd like to be able of modifying automatically the git push:

* unmodified for branches master and dev
* automatically add --skip-ci for other branches.

I know this may be considered a bad idea, but I'd like to know whether it's possible to do it nevertheless :).

Answer (score 0):

One important parameter when you work on several branches is to set the upstream branch for each branch (if it is has not already been set when the branch was created). You should read [this page about remote branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Assuming you work on three branches : 
- develop
- master
- hotfix

Usually, you would want to push your local "develop" branch to the remote "develop" branch, usually named "origin/develop".

If you are on branch "develop" and that you type:

```
$ git branch -u origin/develop
Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
```

The upstream branch is set. Once you have done that, when you type

```
$ git push
```

the push will be done towards "origin/develop". You will not have to type

```
$ git push origin/develop develop
```

This setting will have to be done on each branch. The setting will also be effective on the "git pull" command as you will not have to specify from which you branch you are pulling.
You can check the syntax of the [git branch command here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

Comment: thank you @iclman, this makes sense. However, I understand that the upstream branch is a special case, that can be easily configured per branch. I added an example in a comment above of a parameter that I'd like to 'configure' differently per branch (--skip-ci)